# Multi level menu item does stay expanded when a sub menu is selected

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, aspnetboilerplate

I have an ASP Boilerplate project and I want to use multi level menus but when a sub menu selected and page is fully loaded, top menu must stay expanded but it collapse.[Menu bar must look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJXq9.png) not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhuEn.png) when I select Tenants for example (Management menu must remain expanded).

Comment: Which version of the template are you on?

Comment: Version = "3.5.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in v4.0 of the template.

> You can add the following code in **admin.js** after line `var $activeAnchors = $(val).find('a:eq(0)');`
>
> ```js
> var $parentAnchors = $(val).parentsUntil('.menu .list', 'li').children('a:first-child');
> $activeAnchors = $activeAnchors.add($parentAnchors);
> ```
>
> — [#292 (comment)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/issues/292#issuecomment-406013726)